# Using Single Item template and promoted display template together?

Tags: 2013

Can I use `Item_CommonItem_Body` with promoted results ?

I am trying and getting this error,

> Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it
>   by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in
>   either the Web Part properties or Result Types.
>
> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (CoreRender:
>   ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display
>   Templates/Search/Item_CommonItem_Body.js)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are customized the  `Item_CommonItem_Body.js` (`Item_CommonItem_Body.html->to js`)
and exist javascript error that block the sharepoint javascript to continue to run